# Установка Rails-приложения на хостинг

Tags: .htaccess, ruby-on-rails, хостинг, cgi

Как происходит установка сайта на Rails на хостинг?
Я так понял что необходимо в папке public создать два файла:

dispatcher.fcgi

```
#!/home/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
ENV['HOME'] ||= `echo ~`.strip
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = File.expand_path('~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392')
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = File.expand_path('~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392') + ":" +
    File.expand_path('~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global')
require 'fcgi' 
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../config/environment.rb')
class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
 def initialize(app)
   @app = app
 end
 def call(env)
   env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
   parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
   env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
   env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
   @app.call(env)
 end
end
Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run  Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(try::Application)
```

и второй файл .htaccess

```
# General Apache options
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
#Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

# If you don't want Rails to look in certain directories,
# use the following rewrite rules so that Apache won't rewrite certain     requests
# 
# Example:
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/notrails.*
#   RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Redirect all requests not available on the filesystem to Rails
# By default the cgi dispatcher is used which is very slow
# 
# For better performance replace the dispatcher with the fastcgi one
#
# Example:
#   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
RewriteEngine On

# If your Rails application is accessed via an Alias directive,
# then you MUST also set the RewriteBase in this htaccess file.
#
# Example:
#   Alias /myrailsapp /path/to/myrailsapp/public
#   RewriteBase /myrailsapp

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]

# In case Rails experiences terminal errors
# Instead of displaying this message you can supply a file here which         will be rendered instead
# 
# Example:
#   ErrorDocument 500 /500.html

ErrorDocument 500 "<h2>Application error</h2>Rails application failed     to     start properly"
```

При обращении к странице public/index.html все хорошо, но стоит обратиться к моей странице выдает ошибку 404.

Что делать?

Comment: Для того чтобы запустить приложение на RoR нужен сервер приложений. А это: Passenger, Thin, Puma, Unicorn. Запросы к серверу приложений проходят через WEB-сервер(Apache, Nginx). Папака `public` в директории приложения, содержит ресурсы, которые отдаются напрямую через WEB-сервер. Приложение на RoR нужно именно запускать. Это не просто набор скриптов, как, например, PHP.

Comment: А запуск происходит через SSH?

Comment: Обычно, запуск происходит при развертывании приложения. Если пользоваться Capistrano,  то оно сначала стягивает приложение с гита, потом ставить гемчики, накатывает миграции, потом запускает сервер приложений. При этом заходить на production-сервер не нужно. Capistrano делает это за вас.

Comment: А Capistrano будет работать без SSH? И можно ли настроить на bitbucket?

Comment: Можно настроить на Bitbucket. Для этого на машине откуда запускается Capistrano должен лежать ключ для Bitbucket.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваши ответы!

Comment: Сильно зависит от хостинга, обычно для этого используют арендуемый сервер, чаще виртуальный, с самостоятельной ОС и удалённым доступом по SSH.

Comment: @Василий SSH-доступ в любом случае нужен.